# ADFS / SSO - High Availability Implementation

Tags: networking, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

So I set up an ADFS server and I have it all secured and working with slack, it works very well. I have a few questions regarding High Availability that I can't find solid advice on before we set up SSO for every online service we can.

The current Network looks like this:

```
(All offices are connected via a VPN)
---------
Office 1:
AD-DC1
AD-DC2
AD-FS1 (Prod)
---------
Office 2:
AD-DC3
AD-FS2 (Dev)
---------
Office 3:
AD-DC4
AD-FS3 (Dev)
---------
```

When setting up the ADFS I did not set up any WAP's as I wanted to use my UTM with a virtual webserver.

My question is if AD-FS1 is in production how viable is it to just join AD-FS2 & AD-FS3 to the Farm and then use Network Load Balancing to provide High Availability / Redundancy in case AD-FS1 dies?

Anyone got any gotcha's they have run into when trying to do this or using NLB on Windows Server 2016

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just used AWS Route 53 with DNS failover. As the servers were already connected via vpn. Works flawlessly.